# Variable length arguments in C

Tags: c, variadic-functions

Why do I have to take an `int` type variable in c `var_args` function? Like `printf` is a built-in function that does not require the length of arguments to be declared before entering various variables...

Comment: `printf` can tell what to expect from your format string.

Comment: Than information has to be known one way or another. Take an int type variable is one way. Another example like printf *PyArg_ParseTuple*, it also use a string to tell what to expect.

Answer (score 0):

The C standard does not require a function with a variable parameter list to have any particular argument type.

However, it is up to the function to make appropriate invocations to `va_arg`. To do that, the function has to have some way of knowing what arguments have been passed. You may implement that requirement in any way you desire, including:

- Use a format string that contains conversion specifiers that indicate the argument types, as `printf` does.
- Pass any description of the numbers and types of each argument. Encode them all in one array, pass several arguments describing the rest, describe one argument, then have that argument, then describe the next argument, then have that argument, and so on.
- Deduce the arguments from the operation the function is requested to perform. For example, an `open` call might take flags that indicate whether it should create a file or just open an existing one. If it is to create a file, then it could take an additional parameter indicating the permissions to be set on the file, whereas, if it is merely opening an existing file, it would not take that parameter.

Answer (score 0):

C does not allow a variable argument function to optionally take zero parameters. That is, there must be a named parameter before the `...`.

For `printf`, the named parameter is the format string. When parsing the format string, the type of the next argument can be deduced, and the `va_arg` macro can be properly invoked.

If all the arguments are of the same type, you can use the named parameter to indicate the number of arguments being passed in. For example, if you are passing in a number of strings:

```
void foo_strings (int n, ...) {
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, n);
    while (n--) {
        const char *s = va_arg(ap, const char *);
        foo(s);
    }
    va_end(ap);
}
```

However, you could have just as easily used a `NULL` to indicate there are no more strings. Then, the first argument could be used for something else, such as pointing to a function.

```
void foo_string (void (*foo)(const char *), ...) {
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, n);
    const char *s = va_arg(ap, const char *);
    while (s != NULL) {
         foo(s);
         s = va_arg(ap, const char *);
    }
    va_end(ap);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer has to do with compiler calling conventions.  Here's a slightly simplified explanation:

Basically, when the compiler encounters a function call with N arguments, it generates code to push N arguments on the stack.
When the compiler compiles a function which takes N arguments, it generates code to pops N arguments off the stack.

There is no "secret" information telling the function how many arguments were pushed.  For ordinary functions, the number and type of arguments agree only because the function prototype in the calling code agrees with the function definition.

For variadic functions, it's not possible to rely on the function definition. The `...` literally means "we don't know what arguments will be pushed.  So there needs to be an alternate source for the argument specification.  A simple way to do it is just ensure the first argument is the count of fixed-size arguments to follow.

`printf` and family use a different method.  The format string defines what type and how many arguments it will use.